# How to get limit text around keyword from results with Solr

Tags: solr

I'm adding search functionality for my website with Solr. I created a solr core to save articles(id, title, content). Because the text on content field very long, i want to limit words of results around keyword each time i get a query results (it like Google results).

my Solr version: 6.1.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use [Highlighting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting), this feature is exactly what you are asking for